# Kotlin: format string

Tags: xml, string, loops, format, kotlin

I have a Recycle view that i want to iterate over and add a bullet point in front of each input String.

I have the following:

value.strings.xml

```
<string name="skill">• %1$s</string>
```

ProfileListAdapter:

```
fun bindSkills(skill: String) {

            itemView.recycleSkillItem.text = String.format(Locale(R.string.skill.toString()), ${R.string.skill}, skill)
    }
```

This prints the same int over and over again without the bullet point.

what is the best practice to format strings in kotlin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should learn how Android works first. `R.string.skill` returns the resource id of the string which is an `Int` To get the String, from resource, you have to use

```
context.getString(resId)
```

It also supports string formatting.

```
context.getString(R.string.skill, skill)
```

`context` can be anything that extends `Context`, i.e `Activity`, `Fragment`.

To format `String` in Kotlin, you use string interpolation.

```
val world = "World"
val helloWorld = "Hello $world"  // Hello World
```